# How to pipe stream to an async function and await the response

Tags: node.js

I have an async function that is uploading something to s3. I want to pipe a stream to that async function and await the response.

```
const stream = fs.createReadStream(process.cwd() + "/test/resources/" + "id/front.jpg");

const response = stream.pipe(await storageModule.upload(key, stream));

expect(response.Location).to.equal(`${s3Url}/${key}`)
```

However i never receive the response.

```
public upload = async (key) => {

    const pass = new PassThrough();

    const params = {
        Bucket: this.bucket,
        Key: key,
        Body: pass
    }

    return this.s3.upload(params).promise()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass passthrough stream and promise both from your function like this amd await the promise

```
function upload(key) {

  const pass = new PassThrough();

  const params = {
      Bucket: "somebucket",
      Key: key,
      Body: pass
  }
  return {
    writeStream: pass,
    promise: s3.upload(params).promise(),
  };

}
```

```
const stream = fs.createReadStream(process.cwd() + "/" + "somekey.png");
const {writeStream, promise} = upload("somekey.png");
stream.pipe(writeStream);
const response = await promise;
console.log(response);
```